# How to fit a "freeform" UIViewController to multiple screen sizes?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have created several freeform UIViewControllers that have extra long heights for scrolling purposes, and widths that equal the width of an iPhone 8 Plus screen (because that's the physical device I have available for testing with).

My problem comes when I am trying to make my app functional on all devices down to an iPhone SE sized screen. The height isn't an issue, but the width is creating a problem because on smaller screen sizes.

UIViewController is obviously wider than the screen. so, it allows for horizontal scrolling/panning.  However, my goal is to have the ViewController match the width of the screen being used. so, only vertical scrolling is possible.

I've tried to adjust the width of the UIViewController when it gets presented, but that seems to have no effect.  I'm really not sure what else to try and can't find anything about this online. Is this an obvious fix or am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: the view controller size automatically adjusts to your screen size (provided its properly configured). If you have an scrollview inside your view controller, then you should make sure the edges of the scrollview are attach to its parent view (the view controller's root view) using auto layout constraints. In addition, the scrollview contents must be set to use the root view as the position reference (at least horizontally) otherwise auto layout won't know how to handle the horizontal positioning.

Comment: I have a scrollview inside my view controller, but it doesn't take up the entire view controller.  I have the scrollview attached to the left, right, and bottom edges of the root view and set a specific distance from the top edge of the root view.  Within the scrollview I have a view that completely fills the scrollview and is attached to the scrollviews' four edges.  The entire viewcontroller is still not adjusting to fit the screen size though.

Comment: Attach the inner view (that fills your entire scrollview) to the left and right edge of the root view as well. Yes the parent of that view would be the scrollview but you should also attach it to the view controller's root view as well. (left and right edges only)

Comment: Thank you, this is what finally solved the problem.  I wasn't giving me the option to attach the inner view to root view so I had just been attaching it to the leading and trailing edges of the scroll view, but once I did figure out how to attach to the root view it worked perfectly as I had expected.

Comment: I posted the comments as an answer so that the question doesn't remain open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly answer this question and for other people that might be having this issue.

The view controller size automatically adjusts to the screen size (provided its properly configured).

If you have an scrollview inside a view controller, then you should make sure the edges of the scrollview are attach to its parent view (the view controller's root view) using auto layout constraints.

**In addition, the scrollview contents must be set to use the root view as the position reference (at least horizontally) otherwise auto layout won't know how to handle the horizontal positioning.**

To accomplish this you just need to attach the inner view (that fills your entire scrollview) to the left and right edge of the **view controller's root view** as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be mistaking your **UIViewController** with a view. If your view is a scroll view, you can set the content size of the scroll view to be the same as the width of your device and it should achieve the desired effect.

In **Swift 3.0** and above:

```
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
yourScrollView.contentSize.width = screenWidth
```

Comment: I don't just have a scrollview that I am presenting, I have a viewcontroller that contains a scrollview in part of it.  I have already tried adjusting the width using the method you have posted, but it doesn't seem to work for an entire viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

To support multiple widths you can use different size classes available in iOS.
there are many tutorials available for size-class related constraints.

like https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/designing-for-size-classes-in-ios/,
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/designing-for-size-classes-in-ios/

you should have to give View's constraints in relation to their Parent views if possible for your design.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried to adjust the width of the UIViewController **when it gets presented**

By "presenting" you mean `viewDidLoad` method? I don't think it's the best place to adjust width because at this moment view bounds are not yet known. Besides `viewDidLoad` method is not called when devices is rotated.

I suppose you should update scroll view width in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` which is called every time when root view bounds changed in view controller:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    yourScrollView.contentSize.width = screenWidth  

    // I don't think you really need it 
    // but it may help
    yourScrollView.setNeedsLayout()
}
```